# How to add dagger in my android studio project

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, dagger

I am trying to compress the video using ffmpeg in android. I found one good example and I downloaded the project from https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java. It's working fine. When I try to add that ffmpeg library in my project I am facing error. After make many changes I resolved many issues. But I can not clear the following issue:

```
Error:(34, 13) Failed to resolve: com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2

Error:(35, 13) Failed to resolve: com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2
```

I decided to download the dagger.jar and dagger-compiler.jar. I download the jar and I added into my project. But I am facing another error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':ContainerCentralen:compileDebugJava'.
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/inject/Scope
```

I can not solve this two issues. Please let me any idea to resolve this issue.

Comment: If you are at the beginning of adding dagger to your project and haven't written Injects etc. yet, I would strongly recommend going for Dagger 2 instead. With dagger 1 (in it's current state) it is very difficult to apply proguard to the project, something that is a non-issue for Dagger 2.

Comment: After following the link I realized that you probably are talking about the library. More specifically their app is using Dagger https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java/blob/master/app/build.gradle. Are you sure you need that? I mean it looks like it is a sample app, in which case it should not be included in your project to enable ffmpeg

Comment: I am looking for ffmpeg compress video in android. I can not find any example. But I got this link now. Now I want to add the ffmpeg. So I want to use this. Any idea to resolve this??